FreePBX installation issues - where's modules installation package.json
I'm getting several errors trying to create a docker version of FreePBX. The main problem is several errors on modules versions.
Where is the central package.json that installs modules for fwconsole ma installall command ? I would like to control which version is being installed of each module.
